# How to set an equation to the center of page in latex?

Tags: equations, center

I wrote the following equation:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{equation}
 C_{TOPSIS}= \frac{S^-_i}{S^-_i + S^+_i } 
\end{equation}
\end{center}
```

but unfortunately, the equation is always starting from  left :

[image]

I want to move it to center.

Comment: You don't need `center`. Quite likely, you have somewhere the `fleqn` option.

Comment: @egreg thank you

Answer (score 1):

I will do in this way using all the curly brackets and `\textsc{Topsis}` (small caps).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 C_{\textsc{Topsis}}= \frac{S^{-}_{i}}{S^{-}_{i} + S^{+}_{i}} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]